# serializing json in android using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a json that looks like this

```
 {"abcd": {
     "id": 1234,
     "response": "authenticated",
     "key": "abrakadaba",
     "userId": 5555
 }}
```

and a class that looks like this:

```
public class Login
{
    @SerializedName("response")
    public String response;

    @SerializedName("userId")
    public int userId; 

    @SerializedName("id")
    public int employeeId;

    @SerializedName("key")
    public String key;
}
```

This normally works, but not with a json that has the `{"abcd": {}}` before all the info i need to retrieve.

how do I handle this `"abcd" tag to find and serialize all the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something to wrap the Login to coincide with the "abcd".  gson/jackson/whatever is going to want to parse that first.  You could create a new class that contains a Login.  If that wrapper class is truly going to be throw-away then you may want to just have it parse a `Map<String, Login>` and then do a myParsedMap.get("abcd") to get your Login object.

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked:

```
@SerializedName("auth")
    authorization auth;

    public class authorization
    {
        @SerializedName("response")
        public String response;

        @SerializedName("userId")
        public int userId; 

        @SerializedName("Id")
        public int employeeId;

        @SerializedName("key")
        public String key;
    }
```